# Angular2: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement the Google Maps API application in a Angular2, if I put in the index.html

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=MY_KEY&libraries=places'"></script>
```

It works perfectly, but I need to insert MY_KEY dynamically, so change the tag `<script>` to:

```
<script id="maps-google" src=""></script>
```

And in the app component:

```
this.document.getElementById("maps-google").setAttribute('src','http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + key + '&libraries=places');
```

The fact is that it does not work and returns error Uncaught me ReferenceError: google is not defined, I have seen solutions making an asynchronous call with javascript but not carry it out with typescript, plus the map is initialized and displayed in another component. In the other part I access "google" by (in the other component):

```
let google declare: any;
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476851/can-i-change-script-src-and-have-javascript-run-the-new-code